# Get dimple.js chart

Tags: javascript, dimple.js

I am completely new at D3 and thought that dimple.js is an easy starting point. However, I can't get any example to appear in my browser [Chrome, Firefox].

E.g. this [barchart](http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=bars_vertical) does not produce anything:

```
<div id="chartContainer">
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v1.1.5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
    d3.tsv("/data/example_data.tsv", function (data) {
      var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
      myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 510, 305)
      var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Month");
      x.addOrderRule("Date");
      myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Unit Sales");
      myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
      myChart.draw();
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

I have downloaded the d3js library and saved it in the same directory as the html file. The path of the data file has been checked. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you hosting the page somewhere?  If the URL in your browser begins `file://...` that's the problem.  It will need to be served up over http in order to reference the data, usually `"http://localhost...`.

If that's the problem there are many different approaches to try.  I use node.js to run a web server with express which is a good free solution. Plus the configuration files for this are all in the download so it will be pretty easy to set up.

Having downloaded the zip file from https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/zipball/master and extracted it to a folder on your local machine, you will need to install node.js from here http://nodejs.org/.

Then - if using windows - open the command window and navigate to the folder you extracted the zip file into and run the following command:

```
npm install
```

This will install all the dependencies defined in the package.json file. Having done that run:

```
node app.js
```

The command window should look like it isn't doing anything but if you open Firefox (or any other browser) and browse to `http://localhost:3000/examples/bars_horizontal.html` the example will open up, all running from your machine.

EDIT: I've just written this into the dimple.js wiki here: https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki#wiki-installing-the-examples

Comment: By the way, if you are wanting to modify the example files don't be put off by the message in the HTML about editing templates, that's only a note for developing the site.

Comment: You might want to re-download the example.  When I was testing the above code I realised there was a problem with the horizontal bars file in the download which is now fixed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction John. I have tried: 1. install node.js via the package manager [I am on Xubuntu 13.10], followed by sudo install http-server -g and http-server . -p 3000. 2. python -m SimpleHTTPServer 3000. I then clicked on the example and replaced file:/// with http://localhost3000:/. That produces a 404 message.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with Linux systems.  so I'm not sure about the install http-server stuff.  I guess the localhost3000 in your comment is a typo (should be localhost:3000).  It might be worth creating a simple hello world html page and getting that working first.  Once the server is serving you can just drop the dimple stuff in and it ought to work.

Comment: When I type: http://localhost, I get: "It works! This is the default web page for this server.The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.", so that works. My confusion is the "drop the dimple stuff in" - I see no other way than above [I used localhost:3000].

Comment: If you have localhost available to use, then you can ignore all the stuff about node and ports.  Just put the contents of the zip file into the folder with your default "It works!" web page in it and you can refer to the examples as `http://localhost/examples/bars_horizontal.html`

Comment: The node server : http-server . points to the /home directory. If I put the example files there, nothing happens. I have tried different paths.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is somehow with the set up of the local web server.  I'm afraid I don't know what else to suggest.  You might want to post a new question about this to get help from relevant people. I only have some basic experience of running a web server in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party but this might help someone in the future who just wants the dimple chart experience without the headache...Instead of going through the hassle of setting up a web server and coding by hand and you want to use Dimple Charts you could try http://dimplecharts.com  which is based on the Dimple Charts API.  DimpleCharts has all the dimplejs.org demos pre-configured to assign your fields and data to them. It will even generate dimple charts via a Shuffle feature that does just that, shuffles fields around so you don't have to.  It's pretty neat. You can save those 'chart scenarios' and share charts with your team.